# Procedure executa sozinha -Pascal

Tags: imagem, matriz, pascal

Fiz um código em pascal que lê duas imagens tipo pgm e verifica se uma está contida na outra, porém na hora de ler a segunda imagem, ao invés de fazer a leitura o programa simplesmente avisa que o tipo de imagem é errado, com base no verificador que eu fiz, não sei qual é o motivo, pois a primeira imagem ele lê sem problemas.

Procedure de leitura:

```
procedure ler_img(var o:imagem; var l,c,max:longint);
var y,x:longint;
    s:string;
begin
    read(s);
    if s = 'P2' then
    begin
        read(c,l);
        read(max);
        for y:=1 to l do 
            for x:=1 to c do 
                read(o[y,x]);
    end
    else 
        writeln('tipo errado!');
end;
```

Programa principal:

```
begin
    ler_img(imgO,lO,cO,maxO);

    ler_img(imgP,lP,cP,maxP);

    ocorrencia(imgO,imgP,lO,lP,cO,cP);

    writeln('imagem1');
    imprimir_imagem(imgO,lO,cO,maxO);

    writeln('imagem2');
    imprimir_imagem(imgP,lP,cP,maxP);

end.
```

a leitura e impressão da primeira imagem ocorrem normalmente, mas a segunda imagem não é lida e imprime o seguinte

```
imagem1
P2
3 3
10
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

imagem2
P2
0 0
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque todas as ocorrências de read, para readln. Se você usar o read o "\n" será armazenado.